# get all occurrences from a matched pattern and split

Tags: python, string, for-loop, delimiter, substr

I'm using the following  code to find all the indexes from index 0 to ~ so I could create a row off of each match

```
import re
s = 'product 1 & product 2|category 1|8~product 4|category 3 |10~product 1 & product 19|category 8|6~product 50|category 4|6'

substring = "~"

matches = re.finditer(substring, s)

matches_positions = [match.start() for match in matches]

print(matches_positions)

output 
[34, 59, 95]
```

I'm manually using every index in order to show the following output, I would like to create a function that could split and return each occurrence

```
print(s[0:34])
print(s[34 + 1: 59])
print(s[59 +1 : 95])
print(s[95 +1 : len(s)])


output

product 1 & product 2|category 1|8
product 4|category 3 |10
product 1 & product 19|category 8|6
product 50|category 4|6
```

Thank you beforehand

Comment: Do you need to use regex? Why not using `split`? i.e. `s.split('~')`.

Comment: it doesn't matter if I use regex, let me try that combined with explode, I was just trying to do this in function so I could combine my output with Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `str.split` built-in function:

```
outputs = s.split('~')
```

Here is `outputs` value:

```
['product 1 & product 2|category 1|8',
 'product 4|category 3 |10',
 'product 1 & product 19|category 8|6',
 'product 50|category 4|6']
```